# Error with caret and summaryFunction mnLogLoss: columns consistent with 'lev'

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm trying to use log loss as loss function for training with Caret, using the data from the [Kobe Bryant shot selection competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/kobe-bryant-shot-selection) of Kaggle.

This is my script:

```
library(caret)
data <- read.csv("./data.csv")

data$shot_made_flag <- factor(data$shot_made_flag)
data$team_id <- NULL
data$team_name <- NULL

train_data_kaggle <- data[!is.na(data$shot_made_flag),]
test_data_kaggle <- data[is.na(data$shot_made_flag),]

inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=train_data_kaggle$shot_made_flag,p=.8,list=FALSE)
train <- train_data_kaggle[inTrain,]
test <- train_data_kaggle[-inTrain,]

folds <- createFolds(train$shot_made_flag, k = 10)

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", index = folds, repeats = 3, summaryFunction = mnLogLoss)
res <- train(shot_made_flag~., data = train, method = "gbm", preProc = c("zv", "center", "scale"), trControl = ctrl, metric = "logLoss", verbose = FALSE)
```

And this is the traceback of the error:

```
7: stop("'data' should have columns consistent with 'lev'")
6: ctrl$summaryFunction(testOutput, lev, method)
5: evalSummaryFunction(y, wts = weights, ctrl = trControl, lev = classLevels, 
       metric = metric, method = method)
4: train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...)
3: train(x, y, weights = w, ...)
2: train.formula(shot_made_flag ~ ., data = train, method = "gbm", 
       preProc = c("zv", "center", "scale"), trControl = ctrl, metric = "logLoss", 
       verbose = FALSE)
1: train(shot_made_flag ~ ., data = train, method = "gbm", preProc = c("zv", 
       "center", "scale"), trControl = ctrl, metric = "logLoss", 
       verbose = FALSE)
```

When I use `defaultFunction` as summaryFunction and no metric specified in train, it works, but it doesn't with `mnLogLoss`. I'm guessing it is expecting the data in a different format than what I am passing, but I can't find where the error is.

Comment: This is the relevant line in `mnLogLoss`:  ```if (!all(lev %in% colnames(data))) 
        stop("'data' should have columns consistent with 'lev'")```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to see the value of lev?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the help file for `defaultSummary`:

> To use twoClassSummary and/or mnLogLoss, the classProbs argument of trainControl should be TRUE. multiClassSummary can be used without class probabilities but some statistics (e.g. overall log loss and the average of per-class area under the ROC curves) will not be in the result set.

Therefore, I think you need to change your `trainControl()` to the following:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", index = folds, repeats = 3, summaryFunction = mnLogLoss, classProbs = TRUE)
```

If you do this and run your code you will get the following error:

```
Error: At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to  X0, X1 . Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names  (see ?make.names for help).
```

You just need to change the 0/1 levels of `shot_made_flag` to something that can be a valid R variable name:

```
data$shot_made_flag <- ifelse(data$shot_made_flag == 0, "miss", "made")
```

With the above changes your code will look like this:

```
library(caret)
data <- read.csv("./data.csv") 

data$shot_made_flag <- ifelse(data$shot_made_flag == 0, "miss", "made")
data$shot_made_flag <- factor(data$shot_made_flag)
data$team_id <- NULL
data$team_name <- NULL

train_data_kaggle <- data[!is.na(data$shot_made_flag),]
test_data_kaggle <- data[is.na(data$shot_made_flag),]

inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=train_data_kaggle$shot_made_flag,p=.8,list=FALSE)
train <- train_data_kaggle[inTrain,]
test <- train_data_kaggle[-inTrain,]

folds <- createFolds(train$shot_made_flag, k = 3)

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", classProbs = TRUE, index = folds, repeats = 3, summaryFunction = mnLogLoss)
res <- train(shot_made_flag~., data = train, method = "gbm", preProc = c("zv", "center", "scale"), trControl = ctrl, metric = "logLoss", verbose = FALSE)
```